# Why do the files in the Copy Bundle Resources appear in red?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, resourcebundle

The files in the Copy Bundle Resources appear as
[image]

instead of
[image]

Sometimes, I hence have the error :

```
-[NSWindowController loadWindow]: failed to load window nib file 'Document'
```

but I managed somehow not to have it anymore (I don't know how I did).

I think my problem somehow comes from the fact that I tried to have a French application. I created a `fr` localization and then deleted the `en` localization.

If anyone has a clue... Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my experience with Xcode 4.6.3, the english version is required—localized resources showed red until the English localization was enabled in the resource's File inspector window.

Answer (score 0):

They are missing from the folder.

Sometimes this happens in bundle resources (even if they are there). Build the project and then come back to it, it should be fixed; otherwise its probably really missing so find the file on finder and see if its there.

If you deleted something on purpose then they will show up as deleted there, but may not have updates the bundle resources. Just press minus (or delete) to remove from the bundle list as it is no longer needed.

Comment: They are here ! I was wondering : in the second picture, look at the path. It is not a usual path...

Comment: The reaon it is red is because it is not there. The extension points to the localized folder in the file. Im not an expert at localizing, but I wouldn't be surprised if the english version was required

Comment: In my experience with Xcode 4.6.3, the english version *is* required--localized resources showed red until the English localization was enabled in the resource's File inspector window.

Comment: @claymation You can add your comment as an answer.